# No puedo utilizar Deta Space para desplegar mi API

Tags: python, api, deployment

¡Hola! Intenté utilizar Deta Space para implementar mi API. Seguí el tutorial, pero en la última parte, recibí este error. Lo intenté tanto en Windows como en Linux, pero no parece que pueda resolverlo. También lo intenté sin usar el entorno virtual y obtengo el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modo de desarrollador está activado en Windows, y no estoy seguro si está relacionado con algo en mi cuenta de Deta Space.

Este es el código; es simple porque es el ejemplo de 'Hola, Mundo' en este sitio web.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return "Hello from Space! "
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tiene que ver con la configuración de tu cuenta de Deta Space debido a los cambios que ha habido recientemente. Para activar este modo hay que hacer la solicitud rellenando un formulario (antes podías activar este modo al crear la cuenta).

Más información sobre el "modo desarrollador" y el formulario de solicitud en este enlace:
https://deta.space/blog/post-17#developer-mode

Por los comentarios recientes en discord (05/01/2024) parece que de momento no aceptan solicitudes para activar el modo de desarrollo (developer mode), agrego aquí una cita al comentario:

> 05 de Enero, 2024
> hey, how is everyone doing?
> we’ve decided to stop accepting new requests for 'developer mode' until further notice (this will not be anytime soon).
> the team is now fully focused on the upcoming release of Space OS/Horizon which will include major improvements that require our full attention.
> thanks for understanding & stay tuned!